# Function not defined when running userscript/from console

Tags: javascript, encryption, userscripts

I am attempting to pull a link from the url http://kissasian.sh/Drama/My-Mister/Episode-1?id=36170 (specific page) when running a userscript from 
 http://kissasian.sh/Drama/My-Mister (general page). However, the website encrypts the link that I am trying to access.

Running the following code

```
var url = "http://kissasian.sh/Drama/My-Mister/Episode-1?id=36170";
var msg = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: url, async: false}).responseText;
console.log(msg);
```

provides the encrypted video link in the responseText within the `$kissenc.decrypt()` function.

When running this function from the console on the specific page, the decrypted link is returned; however, this function is not defined on the general page from which my script runs as demonstrated by the code below.

```
var url = "http://kissasian.sh/Drama/My-Mister/Episode-1?id=36170";
var decrypted = "";

var msg = "ui0uI3/FNJEDeMXFKFzBVr30Yc6w34jKMp2NWjnnv355ptM/1h5bostMEAZVqsyi";

$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({type: "GET", url:url, async: false, crossDomain: true}).done(function(){decrypted = $kissenc.decrypt(msg)});

alert(decrypted);
```

I am unfamiliar with CORS, and I am not sure if this would pose a problem in attempting to run the function.

Likewise, I am unable to run the `$kissenc.decrypt()` function by incorporating scripts from the kissasian.sh domain on either the general or specific page:

```
var rootUrl = "http://kissasian.sh/Scripts/";
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});

var jsS = [
    "common.js",
    "aes.js",
    "sha256.min.js",
    "subo.min.js?v=3.19"
];
console.log('Loading scripts ...');
for (var i=0; i < jsS.length; i++){
    console.log(jsS[i]);
   $.getScript(rootUrl + jsS[i]);
}

var msg = "ui0uI3/FNJEDeMXFKFzBVr30Yc6w34jKMp2NWjnnv355ptM/1h5bostMEAZVqsyi";
var decrypted = $kissenc.decrypt(msg);
alert(decrypted);
```

Both of these methods rely on successful execution of the decryption function. The below code executes on the more specific page without using `$kissenc.decrypt()`:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://kissasian.sh/Drama/My-Mister/Episode-1?id=36170", 
        success: function(result) {
            var msg = document.getElementById('containerRoot').outerHTML;
            console.log(msg);
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        async:   false, 
        script:  true
    });
```

However, when I attempt to find the link by retrieving elements from the general page, the code again does not run properly. I expect the `document.getElementById` to provide the correct containerRoot from the specific page, but it instead provides the one for the general page that it is executed from.

In these three different scenarios of which I need one to work, I am unsure as to what is causing the problem(s). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know which script creates the `$kissenc` object? (I looked at the scripts you're trying to load but didn't see a reference to it in them, and there are *so* many scripts being loaded on that page...)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am unsure which script creates the $kissenc object. Running $kissenc.decrypt.prototype.constructor yields an anonymous function that appears to originate from http://kissasian.sh/Scripts/subo.min.js?v=3.19.

Comment: Smart! I figured out the general problem of how to get `$kissenc` up and usable on the index page, but the `msg` in your question doesn't appear to parse properly; typing `$kissenc.decrypt('ui0uI3/FNJEDeMXFKFzBVr30Yc6w34jKMp2NWjnnv355ptM/1h5bostMEAZVqsyi');` into the console on the episode page results in the empty string, so I'm not 100% sure it's what you want, do you want to elaborate on where that comes from so we can verify it or should I just post the answer?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, so the problem that I want to solve is getting $kissenc.decrypt(msg) to produce the decrypted link when executed from the console on http://kissasian.sh/Drama/My-Mister. When I attempt to run this, I get 
 `Uncaught ReferenceError: $kissenc is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:17`.  The message to be decrypted should come from  `var msg = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: url, async: false}).responseText;
msg = msg.substring(msg.lastIndexOf("kissenc.decrypt"), msg.indexOf("document.write(wra)"));
msg = msg.substring(msg.indexOf('"')+1, msg.lastIndexOf('"'));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complicated. The `$kissenc` object gets defined inside the `subo.min` script, which is obfuscated *and* depends on four other scripts already being loaded, *including* `jquery.allofthelights-min.js`. Put those scripts in an array, like you're doing, and `eval` them.

After that point, `window.$kissenc` becomes defined, so it can be interacted with. But there's another problem: the results of its `decrypt` method not only depends on the parameter passed in, *but also on previous calls of properties on `$kissenc`*. `$kissenc` *also* depends on a certain inline script tag at the top of the episode page having been executed before the `subo` script is run, else `decrypt` will return the empty string. So, `eval` that first inline `<script>` tag before loading the external scripts.

Then, there are a bunch of *other* obfuscated inline script tags on the page. You need to `eval` each one of them first, until you get to the one which calls `decrypt` - then, you can call `decrypt` *yourself* and get the output you're looking for.

```
var url = "http://kissasian.sh/Drama/My-Mister/Episode-1?id=36170";
var msg = "ui0uI3/FNJEDeMXFKFzBVr30Yc6w34jKMp2NWjnnv355ptM/1h5bostMEAZVqsyi";
var rootUrl = "http://kissasian.sh/Scripts/";
var jsS = [
  "common.js?v=3",
  'jquery.allofthelights-min.js?v=3',  // this was missing from your original code
  "aes.js",
  "sha256.min.js",
  "subo.min.js?v=3.19"
];
console.log('Loading scripts ...');
(async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  const text = await resp.text();
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
  // Get all inline script tags
  const [first, ...inlineScripts] = doc.querySelectorAll('script:not([src])');
  // we'll eval the inlineScripts later, after the subo script runs (defines $kissenc)
  // but the first must be evaled before subo runs
  eval(first.textContent);

  // load the 5 external scripts
  for (let i = 0; i < jsS.length; i++) {
    const resp = await fetch(rootUrl + jsS[i]);
    const text = await resp.text();
    eval(text);
  }

  // window.$kissenc is now defined,
  // now we can iterate through the inlineScripts that look obfuscated and eval them:
  let textToDecode;
  for (const { textContent } of inlineScripts) {
    if (textContent.includes('decrypt')) {
      // we've gotten to the script that decrypts;
      // don't run it, instead call decrypt ourselves,
      // and break out of the loop:
      const match = textContent.match(/decrypt\('([^']+).+/);
      textToDecode = match[1];
      break;
    } else if (textContent.includes('\\x') || /^\s+_/.test(textContent)) {
      eval(textContent);
    }
  }
  console.log('Decrpyting ', textToDecode);
  var decrypted = $kissenc.decrypt(textToDecode);
  console.log(decrypted);
})();
```

Comment: The solution you provided works correctly as intended. Thanks for the explanation!